# VBA Exclude special characters and numbers but keep spaces from string

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have the text "abcd 24 ef-gh" in an excel cell.

I need to get rid of "24" and "-" but keep all letters and spaces.

I have a function that loops through the text and identifies letters using the like operator. For some reason, it doesn't exclude the "24" nor the "-" for which I added a replace statement before the loop:

```
Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim a, b, c As String
a = Replace(TextToReplace, "-", " ")
For i = 1 To Len(a)
    b = Mid(a, i, 1)
    If b Like "[A-Z,a-z, ]" Then
        c = c & b
    End If
Next i
StripNonAlpha = c

End Function
```

I would have liked to use regex instead of this loop, but I didn't figure out the regex to use with VBA when I found a lot of examples for other languages.

Any regex suggestion is welcome, but I would also like to know why my loop is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simple [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) like this to keep your desired characters (ie remove anything that is not `a-z`, `A-Z` or a space)

*Update:edit made to replace `-` with `" "` prior to regexp stripping*

```
Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String
Dim ObjRegex As Object
Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With ObjRegex
.Global = True
.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z\s]+"
StripNonAlpha = .Replace(Replace(TextToReplace, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: @pnuts Yes.I read the `remove "-"`part in the text, but you are correct that the code preserved the `-` as `" "`. Updated accordingly

Comment: Copied, pasted, ran and it does the job perfectly! Only had to do a replace of doubles spaces by single spaces as the resulting conversion: StripNonAlpha = Replace(.Replace(TextToReplace, vbNullString), "  ", " ")

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a reference to the Regex Library see [this](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/)

Try this pattern

```
 regEx.Pattern = "(\w\w\w\w)\s\d\d\s(\w\w)\D(\w\w)"
```

This will give you three groupings abcd ef gh that you can then work with. Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need to add a reference, as you can late-bind (see below). Plus the OP wants to remove non-matches, rather than match a specific string as you have answered.

Comment: I gave a vote for the reference link but I agree with Brettdj, I want to remove rather than match.