# Is it possible to sort an entire worksheet from left to right using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large worksheet with the following information:

```
1: B T B J S

2: A

3: T S S P E 

4: E O R P W
```

Where the numbers all fall into column A. I want to include a line in a VBA script to arrange this entire worksheet to sort all the letters alphabetically, while keeping the numbers in the same position:

```
1: B B J S T

2: A

3: E P S S T

4: E O P R W
```

This can be carried out on one line at a time, of course, but is it possible to arrange an entire worksheet like this? I know each line being sorted alphabetically from Left to Right will keep the numbers in the same position, so there's no need to consider that. Is there a simple solution I'm missing?

Comment: Unsure what exactly you're trying to do.  You're trying to sort the letters alphabetically in each cell?  What are you looking to do with the number notations?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to arrange them alphabetically, yes. I also wish to keep the numbers in the same position (which, as I understand, the Sort Function won't alter anyway).

Comment: How did an **S** get into row #4 **??**

Comment: Oh.... that was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below code will satisfy

```
Sub Sort()
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    lastcolumn = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim sortalphabet(lastcolumn - 2) As String
    For j = 2 To lastcolumn
        sortalphabet(j - 2) = Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    For ii = LBound(sortalphabet) To UBound(sortalphabet) - 1
        For j = LBound(sortalphabet) To UBound(sortalphabet) - 1
            If ii < UBound(sortalphabet) Then
                Condition1 = sortalphabet(j) > sortalphabet(j + 1)
                If Condition1 Then
                    t = sortalphabet(j)
                    sortalphabet(j) = sortalphabet(j + 1)
                    sortalphabet(j + 1) = t
                 End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next ii
    For j = 2 To lastcolumn
        Cells(i, j) = sortalphabet(j - 2)
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com for the alphabetical sort I modified and to brettdj: [VBA Exclude special characters and numbers but keep spaces from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736071/vba-exclude-special-characters-and-numbers-but-keep-spaces-from-string)

```
Sub sortcells(StartRange As Range)

    Dim strArrCell() As String
    Dim intTemp As Integer

    Do While rngStart.Value <> ""
        intTemp = Split(StartRange.Value, ":")(0)
        strArrCell = Split(StripNonAlpha(rngStart.Value), " ")
        strArrCell = Alphabetically_SortArray(strArrCell)
        StartRange.Value = intTemp & ": " & Join$(strArrCell, " ")
        Set StartRange = StartRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub

Function Alphabetically_SortArray(myArray() As String) As String()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim TempTxt1 As String
    Dim TempTxt2 As String

    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
      For y = x To UBound(myArray)
        If UCase(myArray(y)) < UCase(myArray(x)) Then
          TempTxt1 = myArray(x)
          TempTxt2 = myArray(y)
          myArray(x) = TempTxt2
          myArray(y) = TempTxt1
        End If
       Next y
    Next x

    Alphabetically_SortArray = myArray

End Function

Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String
    Dim ObjRegex As Object
    Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With ObjRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z\s]+"
        StripNonAlpha = .Replace(Replace(TextToReplace, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```